# Execute jar file using hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to execute a jar file which works fine upon executing from command line:

```
java -Xmx3g -jar jarname.jar -T class_name_in_jar -R filename1 -I filename2 -known filename3 -o filename4
```

Above command executes *class_name_in_jar* by taking input filename1, filename2 and filename3. it will generate output in filename4.

Here is my map reduce program:

```
import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

    public class GatkWordCount {

       public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
         public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
           String find_targets_cmd = "java -Xmx3g -jar <jarname>.jar -T <class name in jar> -R <filename1> -I <filename2> -known <filename3> -o <filename4>";

           exceptionOnError(execAndReconnect(find_targets_cmd));
         }
       }

    public static int execAndReconnect(String cmd) throws IOException  {
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        p.waitFor();
       return p.exitValue();
    }

    public static void exceptionOnError(int errorCode) throws IOException{
        if(0 != errorCode)
            throw new IOException(String.valueOf(errorCode));
    }

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         JobConf conf = new JobConf(GatkWordCount.class);
         conf.setJobName("GatkWordCount");

         conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
         conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

         conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

         conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
         conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

         FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
         FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

         JobClient.runJob(conf);
       }
    }
```

---

In `HDFS`, I have put all the required input files.
I have executed below command:

```
  enter code herehadoop/bin/hadoop jar gatkword.jar GatkWordCount /user/hduser/gatkinput/gatkinput/group.bam /user/hduser/gatkword2
```

Below is the error message am getting after executing above command:

```
13/12/29 17:58:59 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/12/29 17:58:59 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
13/12/29 17:58:59 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/12/29 17:58:59 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/12/29 17:58:59 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201312261425_0013
13/12/29 17:59:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/12/29 17:59:06 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201312261425_0013_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper.map(IdentityMapper.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

13/12/29 17:59:06 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201312261425_0013_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper.map(IdentityMapper.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

13/12/29 17:59:11 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201312261425_0013_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper.map(IdentityMapper.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

13/12/29 17:59:11 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201312261425_0013_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper.map(IdentityMapper.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

13/12/29 17:59:17 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201312261425_0013_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper.map(IdentityMapper.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

13/12/29 17:59:17 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201312261425_0013_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper.map(IdentityMapper.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

13/12/29 17:59:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201312261425_0013
13/12/29 17:59:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7
13/12/29 17:59:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
13/12/29 17:59:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=42572
13/12/29 17:59:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/12/29 17:59:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/12/29 17:59:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=8
13/12/29 17:59:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=8
13/12/29 17:59:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
13/12/29 17:59:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
13/12/29 17:59:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201312261425_0013_m_000000
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1327)
    at GatkWordCount.main(GatkWordCount.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Please suggest what needs to be change in my code in order to execute it properly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You have not specified a mapper class in this example, and you cannot use the default identity mapper.

This is because the TextInputFormat you have specified produces LongWritable (the line number) as the key and Text (the line contents) as the value. So the default identity mapper will faithfully emit Longwritable and Text unchanged. Since you have specified outputKeyClass as Text, there is a class mismatch between the key output of the mapper (LongWritable) and the key type expected by the mapper output collation system (Text). You'd get a similar mismatch on the value field, too, but the system failed on the key field first.

To fix this, you will have to write your own mapper class, that takes a LongWritable,Text and outputs a Text,Intwritable.

EDIT: I just had a closer look at your code. You're just using the mapreduce framework to execute a java jar inside a reducer, which seems to be a pretty clear violation of the spirit of Hadoop (computing on HDFS data using MapReduce). I would actually re-examine what exactly you are trying to do with this application instead of spending more time trying to make it work inside mapreduce.

Comment: Thanks Simplefish for you answer. I am novice in hadoop programming and dont know how to specify the input files. Yes you are right that I am trying to execute a class in the jar file. This class will take input files with option (-I=input file which binary file in .BAM format, -R= reference sequence file in .fasta file, -known= Input VCF file with known indels and -o= output file). I want to execute code written in the class file by giving the input files required by class.

Comment: This is not how you use hadoop. I would advise just going through a few tutorials and doing some standard mapreduce exercises before digging yourself any deeper.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code, which is given below:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

    public class GatkWordCount {
       public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text> {
         public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<LongWritable, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
           String cmd = "java -jar /home/hduser/apps/hadoop/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar -T RealignerTargetCreator -R /user/hduser/gatkinput/gatkinput/ucsc.hg19.fasta -I /user/hduser/gatkinput/gatkinput/groupbam -known /user/hduser/gatkinput/gatkinput/Mills_and_1000G_gold_standard.indels.hg19.vcf -o /user/hduser/gatkinput/gatkinput/target_intervals.list";

    try{    
        System.out.println("GATK cmd===>"+cmd);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("p.exitValue-->"+p.exitValue());
         } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception-->"+e.getMessage());
    }
}}
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         JobConf conf = new JobConf(GatkWordCount.class);
         conf.setJobName("GatkWordCount");

         conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
         //conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);

         conf.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
         conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);


         conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
         conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

         FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
         FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

         JobClient.runJob(conf);
       }
    }
```

> [1] Now, there is no problem in execution but reduce job stuck at 66%
>   [2] there is no error in userlogs/../stderr file. Even system.out.println
>   are printed in the stdout file but system.out.println are continuously
>   getting printed in the stdout file? [3] p.exitValue--> in the code prints 1 which means job terminated abnormally but no issues in the log.
>   Can you please let me know the issue with this code or suggest an alternative way to execute jar file? 
>   PS: I can't voteup to the answers as dont have 15 reputation.
>   Thanks.